# Difference between using mocha.js in browser and node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I want to stub some post request to test my Express server. Usually I use Mocha, Chai, and Sinon in Node but [in this example the author](http://robdodson.me/mocking-requests-with-mocha-chai-and-sinon/) is using these tools in the browser. What is the difference between using mocha.js in the browser vs using it in Node?

Answer (score 0):

The major difference is exactly the same as the difference between running code in Node vs running code in a browser, generally speaking. In the browser you have a DOM implementation and access to implementations of various web standards. In Node you do not. (You can use something like jsdom but it is not a complete implementation of the DOM.) What determines whether you'll want to run Mocha in Node or in the browser is the type of code you are trying to test.

Other than this, if you run Mocha in a browser, you are restricted to the HTML reporter.